Generic run-name for pull request and reference based workflows
I need to execute basic verification on pull requests and also manually on certain branches & tags using github actions. I am unable to fix on a run-name that can cover both the scenarios in a readable way. Due to this I have to create multiple files/workflows to do the same thing.
verify_reference.yaml
name: Verify Reference
run-name: Verify ${{ github.ref_type }} ${{ github.ref_name }}

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  verify:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/callable_verify.yaml

verify_pr.yaml
name: Verify Pull Request
run-name: "Verify PR #${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}"

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      [opened, reopened, edited, synchronize]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  verify:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/callable_verify.yaml

Is there any way I can use conditionals to create a run-name that can cover both the above scenarios? Any other option to name the run would also work for me if it indicates what is happening in the build.

Since github.event.pull_request.number only exists for the pull_request event, you could use a ternary operator:
run-name: >-
  ${{ github.event.pull_request.number &&
      format('Verify PR {0}', github.event.pull_request.number) ||
      format('Verify {0} {1}', github.ref_type, github.ref_name) }}

For a push into main, this looks like

and for a pull request change, it's

